# strange undefined reference to .. errors

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fixed-point

i am trying to experiment with a fixed point math library i found [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfixmath) and downloaded it from [google code](http://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/). 
 I tried to compile a simple example project by adding the following main.c file to their source and recompiling the whole thing as an executable.

**The problem**
**gcc** (am actually using codeblocks v1.0) complains about **undefined references to functions** that [i really think the library defines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfixmath#Other_Functions). **Some functions work** others generate **'undefined reference errors'** eg,
 here is my main.c file i tried to add to source files.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "fixmath.h"
int main()
{
    float num1=6.25f;
    float num2=2.567f;

    fix16_t numfix1=fix16_from_float(num1);
    fix16_t numfix2=fix16_from_float(num2);

    //try out arithmetic on the fixed numbers

    fix16_t simpleAdd= fix16_add(numfix1, numfix2);//(this works !!)no error 

    fix16_t product= fix16_smul(numfix1,numfix2);//undefined reference to 'fix16_smul'
    fix16_t quotient=fix16_sdiv(numfix1,numfix2);//undefined reference to 'fix16_sdiv'
    fix16_t sum=fix16_sadd(numfix1,numfix2);//undefined reference to 'fix16_sadd'
    fix16_t difference=fix16_ssub(numfix1,numfix2);//undefined reference to ....

    //print out the results
    printf("the product of %f * %f =%f \n",num1,num2,fix16_to_float(product));
    printf("the quotient of %f and %f =%f \n",num1,num2,fix16_to_float(quotient));
    printf("the sum of %f + %f =%f \n",num1,num2,fix16_to_float(sum));
    printf("the difference of %f - %f =%f \n",num1,num2,fix16_to_float(difference));

    //system("pause")
    printf("please press any key to continue ...\n");
    getchar();

}
```

EDIT3:
//show both makefile and build log

```
//build log
Project   : libfixmath
Compiler  : GNU GCC Compiler (called directly)
Directory : C:\libfixmath\
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Switching to target: dbg
Linking console executable: fixmathexample.exe
obj\dbg\main.o: In function `main':
C:/libfixmath/main.c:14: undefined reference to `fix16_smul'
C:/libfixmath/main.c:15: undefined reference to `fix16_sdiv'
C:/libfixmath/main.c:16: undefined reference to `fix16_sadd'
obj\dbg\main.o: In function `fix16_ssub':
C:/libfixmath/fix16.h:51: undefined reference to `fix16_sadd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
4 errors, 0 warnings
```

//the exported make file

```
###############################################################################
# Makefile automatically generated by Code::Blocks IDE                        #
###############################################################################

# Project:          libfixmath
# Project filename: C:\libfixmath\libfixmath.cbp
# Compiler used:    GNU GCC Compiler

### Variables used in this Makefile
dbg_CC=mingw32-gcc.exe
dbg_CPP=mingw32-g++.exe
dbg_LD=mingw32-g++.exe
dbg_LIB=ar.exe
dbg_RESCOMP=windres.exe
rel_CC=mingw32-gcc.exe
rel_CPP=mingw32-g++.exe
rel_LD=mingw32-g++.exe
rel_LIB=ar.exe
rel_RESCOMP=windres.exe

### Compiler/linker options
dbg_GLOBAL_CFLAGS=
dbg_PROJECT_CFLAGS= -DFIXMATH_NO_CACHE -DFIXMATH_NO_64BIT
dbg_GLOBAL_LDFLAGS=
dbg_PROJECT_LDFLAGS=
dbg_GLOBAL_INCS= -IC:/Program\ Files/CodeBlocks/include
dbg_PROJECT_INCS=
dbg_GLOBAL_LIBDIRS= -LC:/Program\ Files/CodeBlocks/lib
dbg_PROJECT_LIBDIRS= -LC:/libfixmath/lib
dbg_GLOBAL_LIBS=
dbg_PROJECT_LIBS= C:\libfixmath\lib\libfixmath.a
rel_GLOBAL_CFLAGS=
rel_PROJECT_CFLAGS= -DFIXMATH_NO_CACHE -DFIXMATH_NO_64BIT
rel_GLOBAL_LDFLAGS=
rel_PROJECT_LDFLAGS=
rel_GLOBAL_INCS= -IC:/Program\ Files/CodeBlocks/include
rel_PROJECT_INCS=
rel_GLOBAL_LIBDIRS= -LC:/Program\ Files/CodeBlocks/lib
rel_PROJECT_LIBDIRS= -LC:/libfixmath/lib
rel_GLOBAL_LIBS=
rel_PROJECT_LIBS= C:\libfixmath\lib\libfixmath.a

### Targets compiler flags
dbg_CFLAGS= $(dbg_PROJECT_CFLAGS) -Wall -g $(dbg_GLOBAL_CFLAGS)
rel_CFLAGS= $(rel_PROJECT_CFLAGS) -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer $(rel_GLOBAL_CFLAGS)

### Targets linker flags
dbg_LDFLAGS= $(dbg_PROJECT_LDFLAGS) $(dbg_GLOBAL_LDFLAGS)
rel_LDFLAGS= $(rel_PROJECT_LDFLAGS) -s $(rel_GLOBAL_LDFLAGS)

### Targets include directories
dbg_INCS= $(dbg_PROJECT_INCS) $(dbg_GLOBAL_INCS)
rel_INCS= $(rel_PROJECT_INCS) $(rel_GLOBAL_INCS)

### Targets library directories
dbg_LIBDIRS= $(dbg_PROJECT_LIBDIRS) $(dbg_GLOBAL_LIBDIRS)
rel_LIBDIRS= $(rel_PROJECT_LIBDIRS) $(rel_GLOBAL_LIBDIRS)

### Targets libraries
dbg_LIBS= $(dbg_PROJECT_LIBS) $(dbg_GLOBAL_LIBS)
rel_LIBS= $(rel_PROJECT_LIBS) $(rel_GLOBAL_LIBS)

###############################################################################
#         You shouldn't need to modify anything beyond this point             #
###############################################################################

### Resources used in this Makefile
dbg_RESOURCE=

### Objects used in this Makefile
dbg_OBJS=obj/dbg/main.o 
dbg_LINKOBJS=$(dbg_OBJS)
dbg_DEPS=.deps/main.d 
rel_OBJS=obj/rel/main.o 
rel_LINKOBJS=$(rel_OBJS)
rel_DEPS=.deps/main.d 

### The targets of this project
dbg_BIN=fixmathexample.exe
rel_BIN=fixmathexample

.PHONY: all all-before all-custom all-after clean clean-custom distclean distclean-custom depend_dbg dbg-before dbg-after depend_rel rel-before rel-after 

all: all-before dbg rel all-after


dist:
    @zip libfixmath.cbp.zip libfixmath.cbp Makefile Makefile fix16.c fix16.h fix16_exp.c fix16_sqrt.c fix16_trig.c fixmath.h fract32.c fract32.h int64.h main.c uint32.c uint32.h 

clean_dbg:
    @echo Cleaning target "dbg"...
    @$(RM) $(dbg_BIN) $(dbg_OBJS) $(dbg_RESOURCE) 

distclean_dbg:
    @echo Dist-cleaning target "dbg"...
    @$(RM) $(dbg_BIN) $(dbg_OBJS) $(dbg_DEPS) $(dbg_RESOURCE) 

clean_rel:
    @echo Cleaning target "rel"...
    @$(RM) $(rel_BIN) $(rel_OBJS) $(rel_RESOURCE) 

distclean_rel:
    @echo Dist-cleaning target "rel"...
    @$(RM) $(rel_BIN) $(rel_OBJS) $(rel_DEPS) $(rel_RESOURCE) 

clean: clean_dbg clean_rel 

distclean: distclean_dbg distclean_rel 

depend_dbg_DIRS:
    -@if not exist ".deps\." mkdir ".deps"

depend_dbg: depend_dbg_DIRS $(dbg_DEPS)

depend_rel_DIRS:
    -@if not exist ".deps\." mkdir ".deps"

depend_rel: depend_rel_DIRS $(rel_DEPS)

depend: depend_dbg depend_rel

dbg_DIRS:
    -@if not exist "obj\." mkdir "obj"
    -@if not exist "obj\dbg\." mkdir "obj\dbg"

dbg: depend_dbg dbg_DIRS dbg-before $(dbg_BIN) dbg-after

$(dbg_BIN): $(dbg_LINKOBJS) $(dbg_RESOURCE)
    @echo Linking executable "fixmathexample.exe"...
    @$(dbg_LD) $(dbg_LIBDIRS) -o $(dbg_BIN) $(dbg_LINKOBJS) $(dbg_RESOURCE) $(dbg_LDFLAGS) $(dbg_LIBS)

rel_DIRS:
    -@if not exist "obj\." mkdir "obj"
    -@if not exist "obj\rel\." mkdir "obj\rel"

rel: depend_rel rel_DIRS rel-before $(rel_BIN) rel-after

$(rel_BIN): $(rel_LINKOBJS) $(rel_RESOURCE)
    @echo Linking executable "fixmathexample"...
    @$(rel_LD) $(rel_LIBDIRS) -o $(rel_BIN) $(rel_LINKOBJS) $(rel_RESOURCE) $(rel_LDFLAGS) $(rel_LIBS)


.deps/main.d: main.c
    @echo Calculating dependencies for "main.c"...
    @$(dbg_CC) -MM $(dbg_CFLAGS) -MF .deps/main.d -MT obj/dbg/main.o,obj/rel/main.o $(dbg_INCS) main.c

obj/dbg/main.o: .deps/main.d
    @echo Compiling "main.c"...
    @$(dbg_CC) $(dbg_CFLAGS) $(dbg_INCS) -c main.c -o obj/dbg/main.o


obj/rel/main.o: main.c
    @echo Compiling "main.c"...
    @$(rel_CC) $(rel_CFLAGS) $(rel_INCS) -c main.c -o obj/rel/main.o
```

Comment: i think i have. i will post make file if it helps

Comment: The current version of Code::Blocks is v10.05  - are you *really* using v1.0!?  I suggest you upgrade that for starters: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: The makefile does seem to have references to libfixmath, but seems to be an odd mix of fixmathexample.exe and libfixmath builds (the `rel_BIN` and `dbg_BIN` targets differ for example).

Comment: Ah, the makefile remained useful, especially since the build log is not verbatim linker output and does not include the actual linker command line issued.  Interstingly the makefile you posted earlier issues the string "Linking executable", but you log has "Linking console executable" leading me to believe that the makefile you showed is not the makefile in this build.

Comment: You are right. I kept trying to apply the suggested changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have *linked* to the library? Possibly the ones that work are inline functions defined in header files therefore you have their definitions, and the definitions of others are in the .lib file which you need to link against.

Answer (score 1):

You are right the library does provide these, but *"undefined reference"* is a *linker* error; you have to link the library to your compiled object code.  Including the header alone is insufficient, that merely contains *declarations* of symbols provided by the library.

I imagine Code::Blocks' project manager has an entry for specifying additional libraries.

`fix16_add` works in this case because it is fully defined as `inline` code in the header file.